# Heroku server for my app keeps on crashing

Tags: database, heroku, backend

I deployed a react app with the server being hosted on Heroku, and the backend/Heroku keeps on crashing after a few page loads or messages I send on the app.
To clarify, the app works initially with no signs of impending error, and then...crash.
I made numerous changes to my code to try and find the problem. Nothing. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createPool`

Just in case this helps anyone in the future...I set up mySQL DB using createConnection instead of createPool. If I am not mistaken, pool dynamically creates connections so that the server does not crash when lots of users connect to it.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case this helps anyone else in the future, server should be set to dynamic port instead of example port= 3000 or other. the Heroku is using dynamic.the app will run fine and once a request is made it crashes with this log:
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
Stopping process with SIGKILL
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed.
I changed the server port then it stopped crashing

```js
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

Comment: Where do you see an example port? Please read [answer]. In particular? Please make sure that your answer actually addresses the question being asked.

Comment: I have added edit to the comment to make more clear how it is related to the question case, setting the server to run on the wrong port was what made my server app crashes on request.

Comment: That's not the problem in this case. OP's app works for a while, which it wouldn't if it were using the wrong port: "To clarify, the app works initially with no signs of impending error, and then...crash."

Comment: Yes, exactly. I retried the process as described to double check. I reset the port to wrong and rebuilt it. As long as I don't request it, it runs fine with no sign of a crash (just sever listening at) and as soon as I make the request, it binds and the app crashes. I kept it running for a fair amount of time, and it's still the case. the poster did not specify more about the log, and that's how I landed here.